# How to parser bookmark xml using Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, xml, macos, bookmarks

I want to parser bookmark xml that import from web browser.I have reading a NSString from a local file that is bookmark xml file and created a `NSXMLDocument`.The code is

```
NSXMLDocument* document = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:htmlStr options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML error:nil];
```

But there are several DT elements in the htmlStr and they are not pairs.How I parse it,anybody could help me ? or do you have some samples for it? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the DT tag and the P tag are not useful.In the htmlStr which is loaded from the xml file,I replace them into nil.So all the rest are pairs and I can get the correct `NSXMLDocument`.This solved my problem,but not good.